# C# argument " instead of backslash

Tags: c#, arguments

my code is

```
a.exe

string programName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = "b.exe"
proc.Arguments = programName + " \"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\"";
Process.Start(proc)
```

and check the value another program

```
b.exe

MessageBox.Show(args[0]);
MessageBox.Show(args[1]);
```

i predict value is

```
args[0] = a.exe
args[1] = D:\my test\with space\Folder\
```

but the value is

```
args[0] = a.exe
args[1] = D:\my test\with space\Folder"
```

**QUESTION**

```
BaseDirectory : C:\my test\with space\Folder\
so i cover BaseDirectory with " because has space.
as a result i want
b.exe a.exe "C:\my test\with space\Folder\"
but at b.exe check args[1] value is
D:\my test\with space\Folder"

where is my backslash and why appear "
```

help me please...

Comment: Set breakpoint on the line `Process.Start(proc)` and inspect `proc.Arguments`. By the way, the difference between your prediction and actual value is that the "T" in "my test" is lowercase in the actual value, and that instead of a "\" it ends with a ". This doesn't seem to match your question title. Can you be a little clearer?

Comment: Does `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` end with a backslash? If not, why do you expect it?

Comment: Is the issue just that you're seeing a ```"``` instead of a ```\``` at the end of args[1]? It's doing that because the last part of your string building where you set proc.Arguments is adding ```"\""``` which is an escaped ```"```. If you want to add a backslash to your string, you need to instead code in adding an escaped backslash like ```"\\"```.

Comment: @John my question is ```"``` instaed of backslash.

Comment: @insane_developer because ```BaseDirectory``` end with a backslash

Comment: @jeajun Only since you edited it. Your old question title was "C# argument with space". Anyway, did you perform the debugging step I suggested?

Comment: @John yes, already debugging step
```"b.exe \"C:\\my test\\with space\\Folder\\\""```

thanks for pointed out my wrong title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kayndarr already pointed out correctly in the comments, you are escaping `"` in your path.

There are certain characters which the compiler will not interpret as part of the string, due to their special meaning.

In order to let the compiler know, you want those characters interpreted as part of the string instead, you have to write them in a so called "escape-sequence".

I.e. that means putting a backslash in front of them.

Since the backslash itself has therefor also a special meaning as escape-character - you have to escape the slash, if you want it to be interpreted as part of the string.

```
"\\"
```

Will generate a literal string with **one** backslash in it, since the first backslash is used to escape the second.

The fix in your example would therefor look as follows:

```
string programName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = "b.exe"
proc.Arguments = programName + "\\" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\";
Process.Start(proc);
```